# Invalid Syntax when trying to For Loop in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, loops, robotframework

im trying to loop a text while input text but i got some error when running it

```
  *** Settings ***
 Library  Selenium2Library          

  *** Variables ***       

${URL}  https://www.ebay.com           
${Browser}  Chrome   
${Searching}  xpath=//input[@id='gh-ac']    
${Name}  book


 *** Test Cases ***    

Test case Register Positive    
  Open Browser    ${URL}  ${Browser}    
  Input Text  ${Searching}  ${Name}    
  FOR  ${Index}  IN   0   100        
  #LOG TO CONSOLE    ${i}    
    Run Keyword If  ${Searching}  ==  'CONTINUE'   Continue For Loop    
  END
```

> **Error says** Evaluating expression 'xpath=//input[@id='gh-ac']' failed:
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Please Help

Comment: try: 
xpath=//*input[@id='gh-ac']

Comment: @Krzy: no, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When robot translates your statement to python code in order to evaluate the expression, it looks literally like this to the python interpreter

```
if xpath=//input[@id='gh-ac']:
```

That is invalid python syntax, so you get the error.

If you want to use that variable in a conditional statement, the best solution is to use the special syntax where you omit the braces. When you do that, the variable is used as-is rather than being converted to a string before being handed to python.

You also need to have no more than a single space on each side of `==`:

```
Run Keyword If  $Searching == 'CONTINUE'   Continue For Loop
```

For more information in this syntax see [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the documentation for the built-in library.